# PHP pfsockopen - fread() sometimes return an empty string or return less than 5 bytes string

Tags: php, fread

I'm using pfsockopen to open persistent internet in php and using fread() to read the return value. Most of the times it works properly, but sometimes(1/100,000) fread() return empty string or return less than 5 bytes string, AND the Transfer-Encoding is chunked. This is the main code I use:

```
$s_pack = self::buildRequestBody($host, $uri, $headers, $body, $method);
$fp = pfsockopen($ip, $port, $i_err, $s_err, $timeout);

stream_set_timeout($fp, $timeout);

$write_status = fwrite($fp, $s_pack);
$status = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

$s_resp = '';
while (!feof($fp) && !$status['timed_out']) {
    $buffer = fread($fp, 51200);
    $s_resp .= $buffer;
    $status = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

    // read chunked body
    // read content 
}
var_dump(strlen($s_resp));
```

Sometimes the result print property, but sometimes strlen($s_resp) is equal 0, or 1, or 2, or 3... so, it cannot read the chunked body and content.

[the one screenshot for error log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mo3N.jpg)